# Data Exchange and Transactions in Layered Architecture

Tags: spring, architecture, transactions, layer

I have done quiet a lot of reading on the topic but still have some 
open questions. Imagine the following scenario.

---

**[PRESENTATION LAYER]**

You want to develop an application with two access points:

- web frontend (View + Controller based)
- service api

So it totally makes sence to keep the business logic seperate from
these different presentation views for reuse.

**[DATA LAYER]**

At the other end of the layered architecture we have the data layer:

- domain / model objects to represent the data mapped by some ORM framework
- data access objects (dao) providing create, read, update, delete (crud) functionality

This layer is all about accesing your data. Keep all the data access
specific logic in this layer so it can be easily subsituted by another
storage system.

**[SERVICE LAYER]**

This is the layer in-between the data layer and the presentation layer
where all the business logic happens.

---

On one hand I do not want this thread to be language or framework specific,
on the other hand I want to know how it can be achieved with central transaction 
handling (rollbacks, commits). So let's assume we use spring as a convenient 
framework for the transaction management.

**1. Where is the best place to handle transactions ???**

Obviously it is not part of data access objects since you want to
access and change multiple objects during one transaction. Therefore
the transaction handling must be applied on the service level as 
suggested by spring framework.

But assume your business logic does something like:

- a) request some objects from the db
- b) request some remote info about these objects
- c) update the status of the objects in the db

Since operation b may take undefined length of time, you would not
like to span a transactions over this operation since it would allocate
valuable system resources. So some of the business logic has to be
seperated from the rest.

**Does this mean that the service layer has to be seperated in two layers, 
one which is transactional and one which is not ???**

**2. How data gets modified and retrieved ???**

In order to present the data the presentation layer must be aware
of the domain objects. By using the daos the service layer grants
access to these objets to the presentation layer. I see two problems
with this approach.

a) Let's assume hibernate is used as an conveniet ORM framework. 
Then dependencies are loaded lazy, which is true for most other ORM
frameworks, too. So my view code trying to access my complex object 
may get some lazy load exception because the transactional context
was ended by the service layer.

**What is the right way to handle this kind of situation ???**

b) The controller is commonly using some framework magic to apply 
changes made in a web form directly to my model objects. This again 
is outside of any transactional context, which means that the service
layer must provide functionality to reattach model objects to a new 
transaction and save them.

**Is this really the right way ???**

Looking forward to your answers...

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure about the architecture stack that you've got, but the ones that i've encountered most is Web Layer > Service Layer > Data Layer.  that is, you the Web Layer access the Data Layer *via* the Service Layer.  Or you can go 'direct' to the Service Layer to get at the Data Layer.

in these types of structures, JTA transactions are (by when turned on) by default configured to either participate in an *existing* transaction, or start their own.  in Spring, this looks like `@Transactional` annotated on a Service Layer method (for example `updateCustomer`).  if the Web Layer has a controller method `updateCustomerRequest` that calls the service `updateCustomer` and also calls `createAuditLogEvent`, and all of this must be done in one transaction, the Web Layer starts the transaction, the Service Layer *participates* in it, and the transaction finishes in the Web Layer after `createAuditLogEvent`.  if the Service Layer's `updateCustomer` was invoked directly, the transactionManager starts a new transaction around the `updateCustomer` method only.

so, by using a model that the Service Layer is you 'lowest level of access' to the Data Layer, and that the Web Layer reuses/access via the Service Layer, transactions can be shared across the various Layers.